# Can I put delay(500) before an addClass()?

Tags: jquery, delay, addclass

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#info-text-container").click(function(){
        $("#info-text").delay(500).addClass("info-text-active");
    });   
});
```

This does not put an delay on it when it gets clicked. Which I want to accomplish. Why and is this hackable, possible to overcome? Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`delay` only works with animating methods, you can use `setTimeout` function:

```
$("#info-text-container").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("#info-text").addClass("info-text-active");
   }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 41):

Not quite like that, but like this for example:

```
$("#info-text").delay(500).queue(function(next) {
  $(this).addClass("info-text-active");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but The answer above was a little bit better to me. You got a up arrow though ;)