# jQuery - run an addClass sequentially with an .each

Tags: jquery

I parse the page for a class, then run a calc for it's scroll position.  If it's where I want it, I want to addClass, then delay 500, then do the next one...

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    $('.work-item').each( function(i){
        var theItem = $(this);
        var objBottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var winBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        winBottom = winBottom + 200;  

        if( winBottom > objBottom ){

            theItem.delay(500).queue(function(next){
                theItem.addClass('show');
                next();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The scroll portion works, and the items add the class, but they do it all at the same time.  I want them to add the class one after the other, in a queue.

Here's a reference I was using for queue: [Can I put delay(500) before an addClass()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448344/can-i-put-delay500-before-an-addclass)

In the supplied example, the accepted answer uses setTimeout, and then increments the time out.  This method isn't ideal as I couldn't figure out a way to reset the timeout integer after the scroll event had run.

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/wov75m4e/

Comment: If possible , can post `html` , create stacksnippets / jsfiddle ? `theItem` would be an individual element , there would be no `next` function attached , as the `theItem` would be another `$('.work-item')` element ?

Comment: Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do, except instead of inside a ready, it's inside a scroll event.  The scroll event works as it should, but the each loads the affected elements all at once instead of delaying, like it should.  http://jsfiddle.net/wov75m4e/1/

Comment: It's just running them from the same start point with the same delay.  When I want is for the first animation to finish, and then move on to the next object in the .each().

Comment: Try utilizing `$.map()` and the `fx` `queue` ; see post , http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var parent = $(".parent");
parent.queue("fx", $.map(parent.find(".child"), function (elem, i) {
    return function (next) {
        parent.find(elem).delay(500, "fx").fadeIn(function () {
            $(elem).addClass("show");
            console.log($(".show").length);
            next()
        });

    }
})
);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wov75m4e/3/

Comment: This got me part of the way there.  If anything, it made me re-think the iteration steps and see where I was screwing up.  See fiddle for final solution.  http://jsfiddle.net/wov75m4e/4/